# Can't make marionette router to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-routing

I am am having difficulties with making marionette's router to work, precisely the router's controller.
Here is my code:

```
 App.RouterController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
            render: function(){
                alert(123);
            }
    }); 

//Router
App.Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
      "*actions": "render"
    },      
    controller: new App.RouterController,   

    initialize: function(){

        var self = this;
        Backbone.history = Backbone.history || new Backbone.History({});
        var root = "/";

        Backbone.history.start({
            pushState: Modernizr.history,
            root: root,
            silent: !Modernizr.history
        }); 

        // handle history for old internet explorer + normal behaviour
        if(!Modernizr.history) {
            var rootLength = Backbone.history.options.root.length;
            var fragment = window.location.pathname.substr(rootLength) || 'cs';
            self.navigate(fragment, { trigger: true });
        }
    }

});

App.on('start', function(options) {
        App.Main = new App.Main;
        App.Router = new App.Router();
});
App.start();
```

I am expecting that render method from App.RouterControler will be executed on all routes, but nothing is happening, even no errors in the console are showing... 
What am i doing wrong?

Note: Initialize method of the router is working, if i put alert or console log in it, it will show up

Comment: Which version of Marionette do you use?

Comment: v2.0.2, i guess thats the latest one...

Comment: Code posted here is correct. I can't see any issues. Did you tried to declare custom route and action and navigate there?

Comment: Yes I did, but with no luck...

Comment: Maybe you have issues when initializing Marionette.Application or in other places?

Comment: So you want to execute render() of controller for every single route Marionette matches, right?

Answer (score 0):

AppRouter should be initialized. You probably is not doing that. Following is an example as it could be done

```
var firstProject= new Marionette.Application();

firstProject.addRegions({
    main   : 'main',
});

//my router
var MyRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

  /* standard routes can be mixed with appRoutes/Controllers above */
  appRoutes : {
    "first" : "firstMethodFromController",
    "second" : "secondMethodFromController"
  }
});

var MyController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    "secondMethodFromController": function() {
        alert('Hi from inside the controller');
    },
    "firstMethodFromController": function() {
        alert('Hi from inside the controller');
    }
});

firstProject.addInitializer(function () {
    // initialize routes with controller
    new MyRouter({ controller: new MyController });
});

firstProject.on('initialize:after', function(){   
    if(Backbone.history){
        Backbone.history.start();
    } 
});
```